# Complier overwrote bootloader doing a non-programmer upload

Tags: mkrzero

Got this when uploading (no programmer) to a MkrZero.

I had downloaded the board's toolset via the IDE earlier, and uploading smaller sketches worked fine.  On a larger, more complex project, got this:

```
Sketch uses 31000 bytes (11%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Atmel SMART device 0x10010005 found
Device       : ATSAMD21G18A
Chip ID      : 10010005
Version      : v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ] Dec 20 2016 15:36:46
Address      : 8192
Pages        : 3968
Page Size    : 64 bytes
Total Size   : 248KB
Planes       : 1
Lock Regions : 16
Locked       : none
Security     : false
Boot Flash   : true
BOD          : false
BOR          : false
Arduino      : FAST_CHIP_ERASE
Arduino      : FAST_MULTI_PAGE_WRITE
Arduino      : CAN_CHECKSUM_MEMORY_BUFFER
Erase flash
done in 0.800 seconds

Write 31336 bytes to flash (490 pages)

[===                           ] 13% (64/490 pages)
[=======                       ] 26% (128/490 pages)
[===========                   ] 39% (192/490 pages)
[===============               ] 52% (256/490 pages)
[===================           ] 65% (320/490 pages)
[=======================       ] 78% (384/490 pages)
[===========================   ] 91% (448/490 pages)
[==============================] 100% (490/490 pages)
done in 0.234 seconds

Verify 31336 bytes of flash with checksum.
Verify successful
done in 0.075 seconds
CPU reset.
```

---

It sounds like it reset the chip completely... and Windows no longer sees a COM port from it via USB.
I've tried:
* The click and double-click on the board's reset button, including at the start of a new upload of a simple sketch
* Restarting the Windows machine
* Looking at device manager to see if any COM ports show up, even temporarily
* Same cable, same computer, different MKRZero - works

Main question:  What could there be in the project to have caused the compiler/loader to do this?    This is the 2nd time this project has triggered a reflash.   It does use the EEPROM API by A. Christian, but I've been able to use that before without this result.

2nd: Any other ways to recover the board?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Hmm... Now getting a similar result on a small test-the-led-only sketch, on a brand-new just-out-of-the-box MkrZero.    But, that one seems to still be healthy from a running and native USB connection POV.   So, what causes this FAST_CHIP_ERASE?